# Bitbucket Server Webhook to Jenkins in multibranch Pipeline: Error: Jenkins response: No git jobs using repository

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, bitbucket, webhooks, multibranch-pipeline

I have configured the Webhook to jenkins plugin in Bitbucket . Created a new Multibranch pipeline in jenkins, added source with Git and applied the git url and test is success. But while configuring the pluginin bitbucket and test configuration is throwing this error:

> Jenkins response: No git jobs using repository: https://mtd1t@xxx.com/scm/st_tes/zest.git and branches: Scheduled indexing of pr_test_webhook

We are not having the Poll scm option in Multibranch pipeline.

Comment: How did you configure the webhook exactly? Can you post the url that you used?

Comment: THis is the exact link i followed : https://mohamicorp.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/DOC/pages/381419546/Configuring+Webhook+To+Jenkins+for+Bitbucket+Bitbucket+Branch+Source+Plugin?preview=%2F381419546%2F381419552%2FScreen%20Shot%202017-10-23%20at%204.06.16%20PM.png